# Button in form not working properly

Tags: forms, javascript

I am unable to get a button to work as I intend it to in Drupal 7.

I am adding the button to the add content page of a specific content type using form alter:

```
function charlie_get_form_article_link_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    $form['add_button'] = array(

        '#type' => 'item',

        '#markup' => '  
            <script>
                function getArticleInfo() {
                    jQuery.get("articlegrabber.php?url=TEST", function(articleHTML) {
                        console.log(articleHTML);
                    });
                    return false;                       
                }
            </script>

            <button type="button" onclick="getArticleInfo()">
                Submit URL
            </button>

        ',

    );

}
```

I have simplified the articlegrabber.php file down to just this (though I don't think it matters, because the button click does not seem to be executing the JS):

```
<?php

$ogLink = $_GET['url'];

echo $ogLink;  ?>
```

Instead of my intended results (which the code delivers independent of its implementation in Drupal), the console logs the HTML for the add content page that the button is on.

I have read a lot about how Drupal likes to make all button types "submit", but my button is actually rendering as type="button". The HTML from the rendered page (as you would expect):

```
                    <script>
                        function getArticleInfo() {
                            jQuery.get("articlegrabber.php?url=TEST", function(articleHTML) {
                                console.log(articleHTML);
                            });
                            return false;                       
                        }
                    </script>

                    <button type="button" onclick="getArticleInfo()">
                        Submit URL
                    </button>
```

Any ideas about how to get it to execute the code on click rather than returning the HTML for the page would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **Simple Drupal AJAX load with jQuery and delivery callback**  which is explained in  5 simple steps [this page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/simple-drupal-ajax-load-with-jquery-and-delivery-callback).

So include a anchor link through the form alter and have the link render the content through attached javascript file through `jQuery.load()` function.

To attach js file,

```
$form['#attached']['js'][] = array(
  'data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/some_file.js',
  'type' => 'file', 
);
```

For Drupal ajax forms refer [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms-in-drupal-7) official documentation.